# Switch columns in Bulma CSS

Tags: css, responsive, bulma

I am using Bulma in a project and I have a problem with columns. I have two columns:

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column is-5">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="column is-7">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

When screen is wide enough everything looks ok and when it resizes (*768 px and less*) the column that was on the left side of the screen is now on the top of the screen and the other is below.

My question is: What is the best way to reverse this?
I need the column that was on the right to be on top next to the other column when screen is `< 769px` (*on mobile devices*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reverse the direction of a container by using `flex-direction: column-reverse;` as follows:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { 
   .columns{ flex-direction: column-reverse; }
   .column{ width: 100% //just to make sure it's filling all of the screen }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
   @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
        display: flex;
    }
```